# Where's the ProportionalWidths equivalent for 5.4.5 ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext, upgrade, pdfptable

I am using ITextSharp 4.1.2
and trying to upgrade to 5.4.5..
while having adjustments about old codes
I couldn't find out the ProportionalWidths property for the PdfPTable (old Table) class.

Would be pdfptable.SetWidths(new float[] { values } );

?

Thank's a lot.

Comment: Well..
After some tests.

I got sure.

SetWidths is the equivalent property to ProportionalWidths.

Thank you!